# How to make a shiny effect in photshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want a color like the image below. The shiny bronze look.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? This site is not to provide full tutorials, but to answer questions related to design. If you need to know more about the site, check the [help].

Comment: I have tried various options. I tried to see what colours would look good and tried a few shine effects

Comment: @bob3 such as what exactly and why didn't they work out for you?

Comment: Well i tried CMYK combinations and they didn't work. I tried to create blur effects but that didn't make the project a lot more shiny. I then tried to create a few different colours to make it seem sharper but it just made the colours distorted.

Comment: Hello bob3, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please [edit] the description of your efforts into your question, preferably with a screenshot and an explanation why they are not what you expect. As-is, your question is very vague about what you want and where you are getting stuck. Thanks! If you have any questions, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to GD.SE! I'll second what other folks have said about asking a more thorough question, but for now, here's what you can try:

I recommend using a color picker (like [this one](http://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/)) and then uploading your image so you can see which colors are being used where. The colors will be provided in hex code format, which you can copy and paste into most places.*

In order to actually recreate the "shiny" effect, not just the colors, I recommend using gradients and then stacking them onto each other. For a very rough example...

[image]

I'm not sure what graphic editing software you have available to you, but if you list them below, we can help you out with actually making these gradients.

*Be careful about hex codes if you are making something for print, since your printer may not be able to make all the colors your computer can show.

Comment: Sorry, late reply: these are both linear gradients, with varying opacities. I can make a second post below with screen shots of how you can make them in Illustrator, though if you let me know what software you have, I may be able to give something more specific. :)